# How to reload the parent window from a pop-up window by calling a JS function?

Tags: javascript, function

I wrote an html page as if it has a link which opens a pop-up window, and I want to place a button in the pop-up page that could call a function and reload the parent htmlpage apart from re-loading the pop-up window. Can anyone please give me a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Window Launcher:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function launch() {
window.open('opened.html');
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="launch()">Launch!</a>
```

Launched Window:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function reload_parent() {
parent.window.opener.document.location.reload();
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="reload_parent()">Reload!</a>
```

This kind of problem does not lend itself nicely to jsfiddle.net, and can't be done on `file:///` domain due to cross-domain security problems, so you will have to actually run a server to host this. localhost is fine. I have hosted it myself here for you to see: http://framba.ch/opener.html